# Dropdown is disappering from the screen when a popup is opened from that page

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am having a problem with dropdowns in IE6. When I open a popup from a page, the dropdown in the main screen is disappearing. This is not happening with IE7. Even if I open the popup I still need to see the dropdown on the main screen. Can anyone try and solve this problem? I am developing the pages in ASP.NET.

Comment: What happens when you refresh the main screen after the pop-up is opened?

Comment: In this situation, you're going to need to give a bit more detail. Do you have a sample of HTML/ASP.NET that exhibits this issue? Preferrably not the entire codebase, just the part that's having the issue. Also, since people will probably be giving you code samples as an answer, you should indicate whether you're using C# or VB.NET on the server side.

Comment: Gentle suggestion, Restrict access for your site to use IE6 and below. not just this there will be many other stuff you will be fighting throughout your development.